# Download pdf document from remote url

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to get through an API, a live pdf file, and then download that file to my users. To demonstrate the problem I change the url to something more basic. However I am having the same issue. The file is corrupted or something similar. The problem is easy to demonstrate, just copy this code to some route.

```
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf');
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);

header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Result));
echo $Result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf');

header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));

echo $content;
```

Comment: You can open the file in chrome viewer? I am still getting an error when opening in chrome.  Failed to load PDF document

Answer (score 0):

Something at pdf995.com doesnt like your empty post string.

Lose this line:

```
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST,   1);
```

And it works fine.